# Variable path issue : conda command not found

Tags: bash, paths, anaconda, conda

After installing Anaconda correctly. I wanted after finishing the installation to do the following. I forget to do it while installing anaconda:

```
export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin"
conda --version
conda command not found
```

then I opened

```
gedit /root/.bashrc
```

I added at the end of file

```
export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin"
```

but I still get

```
conda --version
conda command not found
```

EDIT1: gedit /root/.bashrc

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

l  did also the following :

```
 echo $PATH

/home/ahmed/anaconda3/bin:/home/ahmed/anaconda3/bin:/home/ahmed/anaconda3/bin:/home/ahmed/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

What's wrong with my code? There are lots path in this path!!

Comment: Is conda installed in the home folder? What's the output of `ll ~/`

Comment: ll ~/
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found

Comment: anaconda3 is installed in /root/anaconda3/

Comment: You installed it in `/root` instead of `/home/$USER/`. You must have been in the `root home` when you did so. please move it to `/home/$USER`

Answer (score 54):

Try adding below line to your `.bashrc` file

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

then try:

```
conda --version
```

to see version

Comment: but I shouldn't need to run 'export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH' every single time

Answer (score 11):

Lets fix it like this:

1. Move it out of `/root/` with:

   ```
   sudo mv /root/anaconda3 /home/$USER
   ```
2. Add this to `/home/ahmed/.bashrc`**please don't use 'sudo' here** simple do `nano /home/$USER/.bashrc`:

   ```
   # Anaconda3
   export PATH="/home/ahmed/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
   ```
3. Source the `.bashrc` file with:

   ```
   source /home/ahmed/.bashrc
   ```
4. Now delete the entry [`export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin"`] in `/root/.bashrc` with `nano editor` or with the editor you used before
5. Open new terminal and check

Comment: But... the documentation says *not* to put it in your home directory (like it warns you not to do that). -- And like... if the supported path doesn't even work right then going down the explicitly unsupported path seems even worse...

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

1. Add this path to your .bashrc file `export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` or the path to the bin of your Anaconda insatllation
2. Then reopen your terminal
3. Type `conda --version`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are installing the Anaconda binary that is compatible with your kernel.
I was in the same situation. Turned out I have an x64_86 CPU and was trying to install a 64 bit Power 8 installer. You can find out the same for your CPU by using the following command. It gives you a basic information about a computer's software and hardware.

```
$ uname -a
```

https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux

The page in the link above, displays 2 different types of 64-Bit installers.

- 64-Bit (x86) installer and
- 64-Bit (Power 8) installer