# conda command not found

Tags: conda

I'm following a [Cousera course on Machine learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-classification/). We have to use some specific tools such as Graphlab create. Yet, after installing Anaconda with

```
bash /Download/Anaconda2-4.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

I had to create a new conda environment with Python 2.7.x (I don't now why they didn't moved to python 3 but it seems that it is the way the teachers do its thing on)

```
conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.
```

And it ansswered me `conda: command not found`

I read the [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908827/variable-path-issue-conda-command-not-found) posted by vincent and tried the best answer by George Udosen with

```
sudo mv /root/anaconda3 /home/$mike
```

But still, I received `mv: cannot stat '/root/anaconda3': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found an answer in [madcurie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda)

> **for anaconda 2 :**
>
> ```
> export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
> ```
>
> **for anaconda 3 :**
>
> ```
> export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
> ```
>
> **for anaconda 4 :**
>
> Use the Anaconda Prompt
>
> and then
>
> ```
> conda --version
> ```
>
> to confirm that it worked.

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 1):

I was installing *Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64* (.sh) and was facing the problem of `conda` not being found as a command.

The problem was in the `.bashrc` entry that the installer was setting. I Needed to add

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

in the `if` entry of

```
if [ -f "$anaconda3_path/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then...
```

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same problem !**

You should know first where you have installed anaconda3. If it is installed in /root/anaconda3 so you should first change the user to the root by

> sudo su

Then you can activate one of conda environments:

> conda activate [env]

If anaconda3 is installed in user's directory such as /home/[user-name]/anaconda3, you should not have trouble unless the path of conda command is not in the PATH variables.